# Docker node - Getting rid of node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am in the process of Docker-izing my companies boilerplate for websites. The current issue I am running into is my lack of ability to stop over-optimising... Which is because I cannot seem to crack getting rid of node_modules >:(

Basically, we pay per the GB for container deployments, which currently 1/8th of that file is the node_modules folder. When people view the site they get a nice app.js which doesn't send down a 100mb node_modules folder, so why can't I build my node SSR server into a single js file i deploy inside of my Docker image?

Is there any secret sauce to make Webpack (1) inline things like babel-polyfill so that I can make a single deployable js file for the server? heres the config:

file: webpack.config.prod.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var commonConfig = require('./common.config');
var appConfig = require('./webpack.config.prod-app');
var commonLoaders = commonConfig.commonLoaders;
var externals = commonConfig.externals;
var distPath = commonConfig.output.distPath;
var publicPath = commonConfig.output.publicPath;

module.exports = [
  appConfig, {
    // The configuration for the server-side rendering
    name: 'server-side rendering',
    context: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app'),
    entry: {
      server: ['babel-polyfill', '../server/index']
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: {
      __dirname: false
    },
    output: {
      // The output directory as absolute path
      path: distPath,
      // The filename of the entry chunk as relative path inside the output.path directory
      filename: 'server.js',
      // The output path from the view of the Javascript
      publicPath: publicPath
    },
    module: {
      loaders: commonLoaders.concat({
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'css/locals?modules&importLoaders=1'
      })
    },
    resolve: {
      root: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app')],
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    externals: externals,
    plugins: [
        // Order the modules and chunks by occurrence.
        // This saves space, because often referenced modules
        // and chunks get smaller ids.
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/vertx/),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compressor: {
            warnings: false
          }
        })
    ],
  }
];
```

common.config.js

```
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

    var sassNeatPaths = require("node-neat").with([
        path.resolve(__dirname, "../scss")
      ]).map(function(neatPath) {
        return "includePaths[]=" + neatPath;
    }).join("&");

    var externalNodeModules =
      fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
      .filter(function(x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
      })
      .reduce(function(acc, cur) {
        acc[cur] = 'commonjs ' + cur;
        return acc;
      }, {});

    module.exports = {
      output: {
        publicPath: '/assets/',
        assetsPath: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'assets'),
        distPath: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'compiled')
      },
      commonLoaders: [
        {
          /*
           * TC39 categorises proposals for babel in 4 stages
           * Read more http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/
           */
          test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          // Reason why we put this here instead of babelrc
          // https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr/issues/5#issuecomment-142313637
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: [
              'transform-decorators-legacy',
              'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
              'transform-react-constant-elements',
              'transform-react-inline-elements'
            ]
          },
          exclude: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
          loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
          loader: "file-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          loader: "file-loader"
        }
      ],
      externals: externalNodeModules,
    };
```

file webpack.config.prod-app.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var commonConfig = require('./common.config');
var commonLoaders = commonConfig.commonLoaders;
var assetsPath = commonConfig.output.assetsPath;
var publicPath = commonConfig.output.publicPath;

module.exports = {
  // The configuration for the client
  name: 'browser',
    /* The entry point of the bundle
     * Entry points for multi page app could be more complex
     * A good example of entry points would be:
     * entry: {
     *   pageA: "./pageA",
     *   pageB: "./pageB",
     *   pageC: "./pageC",
     *   adminPageA: "./adminPageA",
     *   adminPageB: "./adminPageB",
     *   adminPageC: "./adminPageC"
     * }
     *
     * We can then proceed to optimize what are the common chunks
     * plugins: [
     *  new CommonsChunkPlugin("admin-commons.js", ["adminPageA", "adminPageB"]),
     *  new CommonsChunkPlugin("common.js", ["pageA", "pageB", "admin-commons.js"], 2),
     *  new CommonsChunkPlugin("c-commons.js", ["pageC", "adminPageC"]);
     * ]
     */
    // SourceMap without column-mappings
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  context: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app'),
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './client']
  },
  output: {
    // The output directory as absolute path
    path: assetsPath,
      // The filename of the entry chunk as relative path inside the output.path directory
      filename: '[name].js',
      // The output path from the view of the Javascript
      publicPath: publicPath

  },
  module: {
    loaders: commonLoaders.concat(
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css','sass','import-glob'])
      }
    )
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app')],
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  plugins: [
    // extract inline css from modules into separate files
    new ExtractTextPlugin('/css/styles.css', { allChunks: true }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV'])
  ],
}
```

I think that the issue might be the target: 'node' as after reading the doco it looks like that uses require('')

Comment: [webpack-node-externals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) let you ignore module(s) from your bundle. Watch out, installing modules on container start increase startup time.

Comment: I'm having the opposite issue, I'm trying to stop my webpack from excluding